# Trying to insert a table from google sheet to google doc

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been struggling for a bit with this now, and I think it's time to ask for help.

I'm working on a script that will take a range of cells from a google spreadsheet and place it into a google doc.
My particular problem is that the script works with appendTable(), but I need the table to be entered before some data that's already in the doc, not after.

What I have so far is this:

```
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("-----");
var sheet = source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var oldfile = DriveApp.getFileById("----");
var number = Sheet.getRange(row, 2, 1, 1).getValues();
var row = sheet.getLastRow();
var sourcedata = sheet.getRange(1, 1, row, 1).getValues();
var newfile = oldfile.makeCopy("Attachment " +  number);
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newfile.getId());
var body = doc.getBody();
body.insertTable(sourcedata);
```

As I said, the whole thing works without a hitch when appending the table, but when using insertTable as shown above I get a "cannot convert" error.
Can anybody give me a push in the right direction, please?

Comment: After looking at the documentation, I think you need to use `insertTable(childIndex, cells)`  You're putting data where the childIndex should be.  If you only use one parameter, then the assumption is, that you are entering a child index.  But that's not what you are doing.  The code can't convert the 2D array to a child index.  Try `insertTable(0, sourcedata)` and see what happens.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!